# Where is the issue in this code segment that's resulting in the matrix being printed as one row?

Tags: c, matrix, data-structures, formatting

I am writing a c program that should take the data in a file called "input.csv" and write it into a matrix, then create a file called"output_print.txt" that prints said matrix in the following format:

a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i

and it also should create another file called "output.txt" where in the first line it writes out the diagonal of the matrix, and then below it lists all the integers in the matrix in order from top left going down column by column, the content of this file should look something like this:

a,e,i
a,d,g,b,e,h,c,f,i

and the matrix should be created using a linked list data structure, the code is made up of 6 parts:

1. Define a structure for the matrix node
2. Function to create a new node with given data
3. Function to build the matrix using linked list
4. Function to print the matrix to output_print.txt
5. Function to print the diagonal elements to output.txt
6. Function to visit and print nodes row by row from left to right

i also forgot to mention that the linked list structure has to have three members per node only, so I thought the best use was to make it so one part contains data/integer the second points to the node to the right of it, and the third points to the node below it. It should be a structure like this basically:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUNbL.png)

---

Now to the actual issue:
I have written out the whole code but there seems to be an issue in formatting in both files and I cannot figure out where it stems from. The output_print.txt file's content is as so:

**2,9,4,0,4,0,9,0,12**

when it should be:

**2,9,4

0,4,0

9,0,12**

and the output of the seconf file, "output.txt"

**2,9,4,0,4,0,9,0,12

2

9

4

0

4

0

9

0

12**

and it should be:

**2,4,12

2,0,9,9,4,0,4,0,12**

i think the relevant parts of the code are that are causing this issue are parts 4, 5, and 6.:

```
// Function to print the matrix to output_print.txt
void printMatrixToFile(Node *matrix, FILE *outputFile) {
    Node *row = matrix;
    while (row != NULL) {
        Node *col = row;
        while (col != NULL) {
            fprintf(outputFile, "%d", col->data);
            col = col->down;
            if (col != NULL) fprintf(outputFile, ",");
        }
        fprintf(outputFile, "\n");

        // Move to the next row
        row = row->right;
    }
}

// Function to print the diagonal elements to output.txt
void printDiagonalToFile(Node *matrix, FILE *outputFile) {
    Node *current = matrix;
    while (current != NULL) {
        fprintf(outputFile, "%d", current->data);
        current = current->down;
        if (current != NULL && current->right != NULL) fprintf(outputFile, ",");
    }
    fprintf(outputFile, "\n");
}

// Function to visit and print nodes row by row from left to right
void visitNodesToFile(Node *matrix, FILE *outputFile) {
    Node *col = matrix;
    while (col != NULL) {
        Node *row = col;
        while (row != NULL) {
            fprintf(outputFile, "%d", row->data);
            row = row->down;
            if (row != NULL) fprintf(outputFile, ",");
        }
        col = col->right;
        if (col != NULL) fprintf(outputFile, ",");
    }
    fprintf(outputFile, "\n");
}
```

I've checked it multiple times and tried to rewrite it from scratch incase i missed something but i just can't figure it out. I tried playing around with the directions, read throught an i also tried adjusting the logic in the 'buildMatrix' and 'printMatrixToFile' functions but the issue is still there. I've tried modelling the code after the one used by my professor in slides as closely as possible